# Can Robins move their chicks to another nest?

Tags: birds

Wasn't entirely sure where to ask this, but had some Robins hatch on my back porch. About a week and a half in the mother bird disappeared for the day came back during the night and in the morning the nest was just cleared.

I don't know if Robins can actually change nests like that with their chicks or if they may have been picked off, no bodies anywhere. Any insight is appreciated.
The chicks also didn't even have all their feathers nor left the nest

Comment: There are several posts about robins at https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=robin if they don't already have your answer you can ask there

Comment: no robbins can not move their chicks to an other nest,for some types of birds it is possible to move the nest if the parent birds can see you moving it and the distance is less than a meter but it is still a large risk involved in doing so,i have some experience regarding this after having to move many hundreds of nests at my workplace over the years.